# FlowLayoutPanel Update & Delete Records in Database

Tags: vb.net

Can someone tell me how i can manage Delete Record & Update Record from FlowLayoutPanel

So i have 1 user control :
[image: UserControl]

then fetch the db:

```
Public Function FindTasksUser() As DataTable
    Using cons As New SQLiteConnection(ServerStatus)
        Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand()
            cmd.Connection = cons
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Tasks WHERE accountName = @GetUser ORDER BY [ID] ASC;"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GetUser", UserUserAcc).ToString()
            cons.Open()
            Using sda As New SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd)
                Dim dt As New DataTable()
                sda.Fill(dt)
                Return dt
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

then call the function in maincp form

```
Private Sub GenerateTasksUser()
    FlowLayoutPanel3.Controls.Clear()
    Dim dt As DataTable = New ClassBLL().GetTasksUser()
    If dt IsNot Nothing Then
        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Dim listItems As UserTasks() = New UserTasks(dt.Rows.Count - 1) {}
            For i As Integer = 0 To 1 - 1
                For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
                    Dim listItem As New UserTasks()
                    listItems(i) = listItem
                    listItems(i).TaskTitle = row("taskstitle").ToString()
                    listItems(i).TaskSubject = row("tasksubject").ToString()
                    listItems(i).TaskFrom = row("taskfromname").ToString()
                    FlowLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(listItems(i))
                Next
            Next
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

[image: Image2]

I have try inside user control img button this options, seems to delete the row, but im not sure is it the right one and how to delete from database

```
Private Sub Guna2ImageButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Guna2ImageButton1.Click
    MainCP.FlowLayoutPanel3.Controls.RemoveByKey(Me.Name)
    'or Directly to use Dispose
    Dispose()
    'or another option
    Parent.Controls.Remove(Me)
    'or another option i think is:
    For Each control As Control In MainCP.FlowLayoutPanel3.Controls
        MainCP.FlowLayoutPanel3.Controls.Remove(control)
        control.Dispose()
    Next
End Sub
```

And how to update in database when i click Checbox1 and button 2 to save the records in database in column "Status" with text "Done"

Comment: What is the primary key of the record you are trying to delete?

Comment: what primary key you mean, there isn't one. In DB [ID] is primary key with auto-increase number

Comment: Having the primary key of a record is a big help in deleting the record.

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GetUser", UserUserAcc).ToString()` What is the `ToString` for? You aren't assigning it to anything so it doesn't matter but it looks very strange.

Comment: You don't need the extra weight of a `DataAdapter`. Just Load your `DataTable` with a `DataReader`. If you insist on a `DataAdapter`, don't open the connection. The `DataAdapter` will open and close the connection if it finds it closed. If it is open, it leaves it open.

Comment: `ServerStatus` is an odd name for a connection string. You are passing a connection string to the constructor of the connection, yes?

Comment: Obviously, `Dim dt As DataTable = New ClassBLL().GetTasksUser()` does NOT call the Function shown above.

Comment: `For i As Integer = 0 To 1 - 1` I have asked this several times. What does this mean? This will run once, i will always be 0.

Comment: `Guna2ImageButton1` is on a different Form from FlowLayoutPanel3. Yes?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the verbage to go with this code is provided in my comments. This has not been tested. Sqlite is an anethma to me. I gasp at the "flexable" typing.

The actual update code takes a list of the IDs from the original DataTable. You add the parameter once to the parameters collection and then loop through the values to update.

```
Public Class ClassBLL

    Private ServerStatus As String = "Your connection string"

    Public Sub UpdateRecords(lst As List(Of Integer))
        Dim sql = "Update Tasks Set Status = 'Done' Where ID = @ID"
        Using cn As New SQLiteConnection(ServerStatus),
                cmd As New SQLiteCommand(sql, cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", DbType.Int32)
            cn.Open()
            For Each i In lst
                cmd.Parameters("@ID").Value = i
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next
        End Using
    End Sub

    Public Function FindTasksUser(UserUserAcc As String) As DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM Tasks WHERE accountName = @GetUser ORDER BY [ID] ASC;"
        Using cons As New SQLiteConnection(ServerStatus)
            Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand(sql, cons)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GetUser", UserUserAcc)
                cons.Open()
                Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                    dt.Load(reader)
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
        Return dt
    End Function

End Class

Private Class MainCP

    Private UserAccount As String

    Private Sub GenerateTasksUser()
        FlowLayoutPanel3.Controls.Clear()
        Dim dt As DataTable = New ClassBLL().FindTasksUser(UserAccount)
        If dt IsNot Nothing Then
            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                Dim listItems As New List(Of UserTasks)
                For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
                    Dim listItem As New UserTasks()
                    listItem.TaskTitle = row("taskstitle").ToString()
                    listItem.TaskSubject = row("tasksubject").ToString()
                    listItem.TaskFrom = row("taskfromname").ToString()
                    listItems.Add(listItem)
                Next
                FlowLayoutPanel3.Controls.AddRange(listItems.ToArray)
            End If
        End If
        Dim IDList = (From row As DataRow In dt.AsEnumerable
                      Select CInt(row("ID"))).ToList
        SomeOtherForm.ListOfIDs = IDList
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class SomeOtherForm

    Public Shared ListOfIDs As List(Of Integer)

    Private Sub Guna2ImageButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Guna2ImageButton1.Click
        'I don't think Me is referring to what you think it is.
        For Each control As Control In MainCP.FlowLayoutPanel3.Controls
            MainCP.FlowLayoutPanel3.Controls.Remove(control)
            control.Dispose()
            'You also need to get rid of any handlers you have added.
        Next
        Dim bll As New ClassBLL
        bll.UpdateRecords(ListOfIDs)
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class UserTasks
    Inherits UserControl
    Public Property TaskTitle As String
    Public Property TaskSubject As String
    Public Property TaskFrom As String
End Class
```

Comment: the new GenerateTasksUser() is not working doesnt present any results this way. About UpdateRecords(lst As List(Of Integer)) is good idea to mass update but nowhere is getting the correct number from ListOfIDs as i see

Comment: okay i sow it my bad List(of Integer) will take from IdList = row ID understood